# Query contract without sincing the node

Tags: ethereum, contract

1) Can I query the contract address without having the synced node ?
For example in geth I'd like to execute

```
web3.eth.getBalance("0x6090A6e47849629b7245Dfa1Ca21D94cd15878Ef")
```

however the answrer is 0.

2) I know there is metamask, myetherwallet etc where I can query contract without having the full node. Why is it possible? How about clients such as parity, geth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a fully synced node in order to get the correct balance. However, you don't need to use a local node. MetaMask uses [Infura](https://infura.io/) and MEW lets you use one of many different providers. You can connect to one of those providers and use their fully synced node to get the correct balance.

Comment: Is there a CLI that connect to a distant node so that I dont need to sync it ? Now Im aware only about web browser extensions working like this.

Comment: Yes. Truffle can be configured to connect to a remote provider.

Comment: The transactions are done continuously, many of them every second. How can be the node kept synced, since the time I finished with syncing ? It must be outdated every while after syncing... Or maybe I don't understand some basic idea ..

Comment: Nodes should always be syncing and adding new blocks to the chain (roughly every 15 seconds). I think you need to read up on some of the fundamentals on how blocks are added to the chain, confirmations, uncle blocks, etc.